# ActionbarSherlock dynamic text-overlay

Tags: android, overlay, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

I'm working on an app that displays photos fullscreen. Each photo has a caption/description that will be displayed as transparent overlay when click on the photo, as example MonaLisa painting photo is shown, when tap on it an overlay of its historical fact will display (scroll up from bottom), tap again to hide.

What's the best way to do this? I'm working on using the Actionbar Split-action bottom menu but is there a better/less overkill way since it's not "action" per-say, and will the height of the bottom bar dynamically change based on the size of the caption?

Thanks!

Comment: check [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) it have very cool features check the [demo app here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.senab.photoview.sample)

Comment: @AhmadAl-Kayyali thanks but there is no text overlay feature in PhotoView

Comment: why don't use this trick to achieve your goal [Android Layout Tricks #3: Optimize by merging](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html)

Comment: @AhmadAl-Kayyali will look into this thanks! (though i'm looking for more of a plugin/library feature than doing this manually.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't use this trick to achieve your goal from [Android Layout Tricks #3: Optimize by merging](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html)

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ImageView  
    ... />

<TextView
 ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

I end up using the TextView merge with ImageView method based on 3rd comment of Ahmad Al-Kayyali.